# is there a way to find what names values of "..." would get if I were to use them with a given function?

Tags: r, function

```
    other.function <- function( x, y ) {

    }

    my.function <- function( ... ) {

        the.args <- figure.it.out( other.function, ... )

    }

    my.function(   1, 2 ) ## the.args would now be: list( x=1, y=2 )
    my.function( y=1, 3 ) ## the.args would now be: list( x=3, y=1 )
```

Is there a way to figure out what part of `...` would be applicable to a given other function, and, in list form, what names they would end up having?

It should also be able to *do the right thing* if other.function accepts ... (not examplified above).

Answer (score 3):

Usually the best practice is to store `...` arguments in a list and later access using the names of arguments. It is kind of similar to what you see in `**kwargs` in python. 
For example:

```r
f1 = function(x,y){
}

f2 = function(...){
    arguments = list(...)
    do.something = f1(x=argumetns$x, y = arguments$y)
}
```

Ofcourse, the one downside of this is that it isn't quite clear, with what names should the arguments be passed. One way to address that is with comprehensive documentation or else you could put in checks to ensure that arguments have been passed before executing the function.

For example, you could ensure that user has passed argument `x` before making the function call with something like following:

```r
f2 = function(...){
    arguments = list(...)
    if(is.null(arguments$x) || is.null(arguments$y)){
        stop('f2 missing the value for argument x or y')
    } #this will halt the execution and alert the user of missing x or y argument

    do.something = f1(x = arguments$x, y = arguments$y)
}
```

I have found using `is.null()` as a check for missing arguments to be very useful. If the user has not supplied a particular argument, say `x`, then `is.null(arguments$x)` would return `TRUE`.

Comment: checking with is.null requires the user to name his arguments, though?

Comment: yes, the user should name his/her arguments while passing, otherwise they will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you expect :

```
other.function <- function(x,y) {}

my.function <- function( ..., other.function ) {
  argsin <- list(...)
  argsfn <- formalArgs(other.function)
  # Unknown arguments
  unknown <- setdiff(names(argsin),argsfn)
  if(any(unknown!="")) {stop(paste("wrong argument(s):",unknown[unknown!=""]))}
  common.args <- intersect(names(argsin),argsfn)
  other.args <- setdiff(argsfn,names(argsin))
  # Recognised arguments
  l <- argsin[common.args]
  argsin[common.args]<-NULL
  # Other arguments
  names(argsin) <- other.args
  as.list(unlist(list(l,argsin)))
}

my.function(   1, 2,other.function = other.function ) ## the.args would now be: list( x=1, y=2 )
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2

my.function( y =1, 3,other.function = other.function ) ## the.args would now be: list( x=3, y=1 )

$y
[1] 1

$x
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks, though not quite. It fails if you try with for example x=list(NULL,NA)

Comment: I tried to give the general direction, but to check any of the special cases, this would probably require more time / test

Comment: np, I'm grateful for the input. I can likely work on this to make it work well for me.

I also wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier approach before I started. I mean functions do resolve triple-dots based on their signatures. What ever code that involves might be exposed for general usage such as above.